# Не работает маршрутизация изображений golang gin

Tags: golang, golang-gin

У меня есть загрузка статических файлов на golang, фреймворк Gin.

```go
func main() {
    // Установка роутера Gin
    router := gin.Default()

    router.Static("/css", "./css")
```

В html такие пути

```html
<img src= "/css/img/logo3.png">
```

а в самой директории проекта есть папка css, в ней папка img и там изображения.

Но почему-то при запуске всё равно выдаёт 404

Comment: Этого просто не может быть. Проверьте, что в той папке, из которой вы вызываете программу, есть `./css`. Убедитесь, что в этой папке есть подпапка `img` и файл `logo3.png`. Можете добавить эту проверку в свою программу [вот так](https://go.dev/play/p/w-gWNWrsniv)